# How to create two objects that screw into one another

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I am trying to create two objects that screw into each other, very much like nuts and bolts, for 3d printing purposes. I started with two very simple shapes:

[image]

I am applying screw to them separately with the same parameters:

turns=3, center=0,6,0, axis=1,0,0

However, at the end, my shapes don't fit into each other:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more robust approach is to 'model the gap'.

i.e. keep the inside and outside profiles as one object, (possibly reserving an 
 <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instance of the combined  profile for convenient editing, ) *then* assign the screw modifier, *then* separate the surfaces.

[image]

(Which you can do by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> select linked, and <kbd>P</kbd> > separate selection ). You can flip the normals of the female component, and embed it wherever it is needed, later on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the offset right. Click the vertex that would be on the spinning axis, and snap the cursor to it. In object mode, make "Origin to Cursor". Now do it for both, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Which vertex would that be? The topmost vertex for both shapes? Also, how do I snap my cursor to a vertex?

Comment: Just search for blender screw, there are plenty of explanatory videos.